# Plotting a harmonic potential as a function of distance or angles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the harmonic potential U = 0.5 k(x-x_0)^2. as a function of distance and the angles. I'm taking the distance between the atoms and the angles between them from a .dat file, which I'll provide below, but I'm getting the strange plotting result. Am I missing something in the code??

Here is my code

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#angles
a_i, a_j, a_k, theta_0, k_theta = np.loadtxt('angles.dat', unpack=True)

#bonds
b_i, b_j, r_0, k_b = np.loadtxt('bonds.dat',unpack=True)

def U_angles(theta, theta_0, k_theta):
    U = 0.5*k_theta*(theta-theta_0)**2
    return U

def U_bonds(r, r_0, k_b):
    U = 0.5*k_b*(r-r_0)**2
    return U
r = b_j - b_i
plt.plot(r, U_bonds(r, r_0, k_b))
plt.show()
```

Here are the data file, which I'm using
[Data files](https://github.com/mahesh27dx/molecular_phys/tree/main/HW_4)

Comment: "the strange plotting result" - what _is_ the result? Why is it strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array `r` contains some values multiple times and is not sorted. Matplotlib plots the values as you provide them. You have to sort your array and find the corresponding `U` values. Luckily, [`np.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) does all this for us - returns unique values, sorts them, and returns their indexes, if you ask nicely:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#angles
a_i, a_j, a_k, theta_0, k_theta = np.loadtxt('angles.dat', unpack=True)

#bonds
b_i, b_j, r_0, k_b = np.loadtxt('bonds.dat',unpack=True)

def U_angles(theta, theta_0, k_theta):
    U = 0.5*k_theta*(theta-theta_0)**2
    return U

def U_bonds(r, r_0, k_b):
    U = 0.5*k_b*(r-r_0)**2
    return U

r = b_j - b_i
Uplot = U_bonds(r, r_0, k_b)

#find unique, sorted r-values and retrieve their indexes
rplot, rind = np.unique(r, return_index=True)

plt.plot(rplot, Uplot[rind])
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

However, this is a patchwork solution. If `U_bonds` were a function containing a complicated calculation, you would fare better to only calculate the `U`-values for unique `r`-values.

```
...
r = b_j - b_i

#find unique, sorted r-values and retrieve their indexes
_, rind = np.unique(r, return_index=True)

plt.plot(r[rind], U_bonds(r[rind], r_0[rind], k_b[rind]))
plt.show()
```